# Maximum overlapping spheres

Tags: algorithm, overlap

I found almost all kinds of algorithm for **non-**overlapping spheres and rectangles, but my problem is opposite of them: Basically it's a problem of different molecules in a gas under pressure. I know there is a "maximum circles overlapping algorithm" I wanted to start with, but I can't find it any more.

Simply spoken I have a lot of spheres in a 3d coordinate system (long integer coordinates), all with different radii. I have to find that area, that is "influenced" by the most spheres, i.e. a list of points inside the most spheres.

Solving with brute force, i.e. trying all coordinates, would take a year. So that's not an option.

**EDIT:**

My current approach is randomly poking around (say 10.000 times) in a box cotaining all spheres and counting the number of spheres I'm in at each given point. Take the point with maximum hits. Let's say at (x1, y1, z2) I'm in 250 of the 1000 points.
Then I subdevice the entire region in eight smaller parts, half in width, half in width, half in length. I can count the spheres touching or being inlucded in a box. So I can ignore every box with fewer than 250 hits.
Then I divide each of the remaining boxes again, sorting out all boxes with fewer hits. Now I have boxes with at least 250 hits.

Now again I can poke around 10.000 times in each box to get a higher score and eleminate further boxes with lower score. And so on. Surely not efficient, but will it work? I'll give it a try.

Comment: Not sure if it's the best approach, but one could start by finding all pairwise intersecting spheres. This can be done relatively fast e.g. with the help of a spatial hierarchy. Pairwise intersection between all spheres in a set is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for a shared intersection volume. Then, these 'cliques' of spheres could be further checked in order, for the actual intersection. How many spheres are we talking about?

Comment: We're talking about ca. 1000 spheres, and most of the time they build only one big cluster, i.e. every sphere influences every other sphere, either directly or indirectly over some other spheres. The spheres represent the influence radii, while only the tiny molecules in the center itselves can collide.

Comment: What is the "list of points"? Is that the centres of the given spheres? Is it a separately given finite list of points? (If so, how many?)

Comment: If it is a separately given list of less than, say, 10 million points: Just iterate over each point, and measure the distance from it to each sphere, incrementing the point's total count whenever its distance is less than that particular sphere's radius.

Comment: Yeah, the list of points contains the center of the sphere (x, y, z) and the radius). The list contains approx. 1000 entries.

Comment: Instead of "poking around randomly", why not just test the ~1000 sphere centres?

Comment: Because that's no guarantee to find a value for common hits > 1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how efficient this is, but I would solve this with a [max priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) and an [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

The nodes in my R-tree would have something like the following attributes.

```
min_x
max_x
min_y
max_y
min_z
max_z
count of spheres we are inside of
count of spheres we intersect (partially)
list of spheres we intersect (sometimes unpopulated)
next expansion direction (x-axis, y-axis, z-axis)
child 1 (may be null)
child 2 (may be null)
```

The priority queue is a queue of unexpanded nodes in our tree, organized by maximum possible inside+intersecting spheres.

In pseudocode the answer looks like:

while we don't have enough points:
take the next unexpanded node
if no spheres partially intersect it:
add all points inside of it
else:
split the node to make 2 new ones
put both nodes back in the queue

When we split the node, we "snap to grid".  That is, rather than splitting on an arbitrary plane and representing all of space, we split on our plane and make each box be the bounds of the grid points inside of it.  We then see which spheres that partially intersect the parent include or partially include the child box.  After we expand far enough, we'll get a "box" consisting of a single point that cannot partially intersect spheres.

Therefore this is guaranteed to find the grid points, sorted by how many spheres it is in, producing the maximal points first.  Furthermore we only have to do our intersection calculations for boxes touching the edge of a sphere, which reduces redundant calculations.